# How to implement auto layout for dynamically created controls?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, autolayout

I have dynamically created some controls to appear at the bottom of the device ,for that i need to give frame for all the controls based on the device height.But this is complex when device height gets changed,My code is

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    if([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height==568)
    {
        xaxis=25;
        yaxis=350;
    }
    else
    {
        xaxis=25;
        yaxis=260;
    }

    UILabel *label1=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xaxis+35, yaxis+35, 250, 50)];

    label1 =@“This is first Label;

    UILabel *label2=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xaxis+100, yaxis+50, 120,50)];

    label2.text=@"This is second Label";


    [self.view addSubview: label1];
    [self.view addSubview: label2];

}
```

Any one can suggest how to implement auto layout for these controls as well as it should adjust while personal hotspot is enabled.

Comment: use constraint to manage the control both 3.5" and 4"

Comment: Use [parentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:...

Comment: can u explain it briefly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create all the auto layout constraints programmatically.
Just use the `addConstraint` method as you can see below

```
CGFloat bottom = 10;
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:bottom]];
```

You also need to create add other constraints as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!I added the constraint with bottom value as 0,My label appears at the bottom as well as left with only some text appears.why it appears like this?.Wheather i need to give NSLayoutAttributeLeft,NSLayoutAttributeWidth,NSLayoutAttributeHeight constraint for the controls?

Comment: @StackUser Try to use [self layoutSubtreeIfNeeded] method after adding subviews.

Comment: can u edit my code my making the label to appear at the bottom of the screen.(i.e label1 above label2)

Comment: @StackUser just create constraints in some testing nib-file as you need and then create all the constraints but programmatically in your class. Give close attention to object which you add constraints to.